# PHPUnit @depends annoation doesn't work

Tags: php, yii2, phpunit

When I coding phpunit testcase with @depends(in Yii2), this testcase with @depends will be skipped.It seems that the function be depended on cannot be found.
Here is the code:

### testcase code:

```
 class GoodsServiceTest extends \PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
{
    private $service;

    public function pull(){
        return [1,2];
    }

    /**
     * @depends pull
     */
    public function testPush($stack){
        $this->assertEquals([1,2],$stack);
    }
}
```

#### console message after running test:

```
E:\xampp_5_5_32\php\php.exe C:/Users/huzl/AppData/Local/Temp/ide-phpunit.php --bootstrap E:\MIC\vagrant\rental\frontend\tests\_bootstrap.php --no-configuration --filter "/::testPush( .*)?$/" frontend\tests\example\GoodsServiceTest E:\MIC\vagrant\rental\frontend\tests\example\GoodsServiceTest.php
Testing started at 15:35 ...
PHPUnit 4.8.27 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.

This test depends on "frontend\tests\example\GoodsServiceTest::pull" to pass.

Time: 430 ms, Memory: 4.50MB

No tests executed!

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: Shouldn't the `pull` needs to have a assert which passes? When `testPush` is depends on `push`, `push` it self need to be successful before executing `testPush`

Comment: replace your image to your code and error

Comment: @masterFly i think so, but i don't know why.Is any possible that `push` cannot be found?

Comment: I don't think so. But I think, in this case what you need is `@before`. so you can have a `private` function for `push` and add `@before testPush` annotation for `push` function. So that it will execute before the `testPush` executes

Comment: Actually, I just try to use @depends,but it cannot work normally.I have spend lots of hours on it which make me feel boring.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found out that I must run the whole test class `GoodsServiceTest` but not only the test method `testPush`.At the same time,I must confirm `testPull` writing before `testPush`.
Hoping this answer will help someone else

```
class GoodsServiceTest extends \PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
{
    private $service;

    public function testPull(){
          return [1,2];
    }


    /**
     * @depends pull
     */
    public function testPush($stack){
        $this->assertEquals([1,2],$stack);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Test can only depend on other tests.
`pull` is not a test because it has no testPrefix.

But what you actually want to use is [data provider](https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/writing-tests-for-phpunit.html#writing-tests-for-phpunit.data-providers).

```
class GoodsServiceTest extends \PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
{
    private $service;

    public function getStacks()
    {
        return [ //a list of test calls
                   [ // a list of test arguments
                       [1,2], //first argument
                       3 //second argument
                   ],
                   [
                       [3,5],
                       8
                   ]
               ];
    }


    /**
     * @dataProvider getStacks
     */
    public function testStacks($stack, $expectedResult)
    {
        $this->assertEquals($expectedResult, array_sum($stack));
    }
}
```

Comment: After replace `pull` to `testPull`, it didn't work yet.

Comment: Have you changed annotation to `@depends testPull`?

Comment: Of course,and the application didn't step into `testPull`